# All Scores For A User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, has-many, belongs-to

I have a table set up that has 4 columns: Name, Date, Score, Grade. Throughout the table, there are many duplicates in the name category. When I click on a name, I'd like it to show all Scores, Grades and respective Dates for that user.

Currently, when I click on a name that appears multiple times in the table, it only shows me the Score, Grade and Date for the instance I selected. How do I go about having it show me all Scores, Grades and Dates associated with that name.

Here is a database snapshot -

Scores Table:

```
class CreateScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :scores do |t|
       t.string :name   
       t.integer :score
       t.date :fielded
       t.string :grade
       t.integer :name_id

       t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

Students Table:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

Here is the table as displayed in my view -

```
<% @score.each do |score| %>
  <tr class="tableline" >
     <td class="tableline"><%= link_to score.name.upcase, score, {style: 'color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; opacity:1'} %></td>
     <td class="tableline"><%= score.fielded %></td>
     <td class="tableline"><%= score.score %></td>
     <td class="tableline"><%= score.grade %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Show us your codes please

Comment: You should have unique `names` in the table.

Comment: Plz show your code and db snapshot to understand the issue

Comment: Sorry about that, added some code. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you need some re-factoring to your tables as well, as an example you should probably having a users table and a related grades table.

Ex:

```
#users table
id
name

#grades table
id
user_id
score
grade
date
```

active record models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :grades
end

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

to get all the grades to for a user

```
user = User.find(id)
user.grades
```